# GetRange of List as Reference

Tags: c#, ref, .net-7.0

I want to get a sub-list from the list and perform an operation on it. And the result should be applied to the main list

```
var myNumber = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 9, 7, 2, 8, 2 };
var subNumbers = myNumber.GetRange(2, 4); // { 9, 7, 2, 8 }
for (int i = 0; i < subNumbers.Count; i++)
{
    subNumbers[i] = (int)Math.Pow(subNumbers[i], 2); // {81, 49, 4, 64 }
}

// For example, applied to 'myNumbers'

WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myNumbers)); // I want the output to be: { 1, 5, 81, 49, 4, 64, 2 }
```

Comment: [`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan<T>(List<T> list)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan?view=net-7.0#system-runtime-interopservices-collectionsmarshal-asspan-1(system-collections-generic-list((-0)))). Heed the warning **Items should not be added or removed from the List<T> while the Span<T> is in use.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan<T>(List<T> list)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan?view=net-7.0#system-runtime-interopservices-collectionsmarshal-asspan-1(system-collections-generic-list((-0)))).

```
var myNumber = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 9, 7, 2, 8, 2 };
var subNumbers = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(myNumber).Slice(2, 4);
for (int i = 0; i < subNumbers.Length; i++)
{
    subNumbers[i] = (int)Math.Pow(subNumbers[i], 2)
}
```

[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMAWAbj0JMwDoAlaYASwFsBTOgSSmA7AB7AA4BlAQDcWAYw4BnKrjwSAhmCJsAngDkIbAEYCiAXiJQOAdyIAZFnOAAeFnwB8ACgCURAN5FMMIgBWAIBOAIB2APQAgA4oogBfRVV1OQh9XQMBORMiAGFBABtCjmlWQSg5AFk1OQALFUK6AEE5UWEVKDctTMMwDzpRQpkON2iiMg9FADNBdTdnYCIWXIIKZaIHIjSMvT65OmsOKABzYDr1lkREDzxvPCJH7fTe7IBtFgBdXIW+DxrznQAAqCCxuHavMByD6fKJTIgAegRPhi/gmYQmAQAbGREngEnhqJgQm5SAQ6AApQTONwAIgC9I0Oj2Ag88KAA==).

---

The MSDN page has the warning:

> Items should not be added or removed from the `List<T>` while the `Span<T>` is in use.

Make sure you heed that warning! If you add items from the `List<T>` then the backing array might be re-allocated, and the `Span<T>` will point to memory which is not longer being used by the `List<T>`. If you remove items which were in view of the `Span<T>`, then the `Span<T>` will not be updated to exclude the removed items, and may still contain them.

Comment: Interesting - could you please clarify why you need `Slice` instead of just creating desired [span with start/end](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan?view=net-7.0#system-memoryextensions-asspan-1(-0()-system-int32-system-int32))?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You linked a different method, which creates a slice from an ArraySegment. The method I'm using doesn't take start/end parameters, see the link at the top of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var myNumber = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 9, 7, 2, 8, 2 };

int startIdx = 2;
int count = 4;

for (int i = startIdx; i < startIdx + count; i++)
{
    myNumber[i] = (int)Math.Pow(myNumber[i], 2);
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myNumber)); // Output: 1, 5, 81, 49, 4, 64, 2
```

To have the changes made to subNumbers reflected in the main list (myNumber), you can't just use the GetRange method, because it creates a new list rather than giving you a direct reference to the portion of the original list.

One way to achieve what you want is to directly modify the original list (myNumber) within the specified range

Comment: Yes I know. The example I gave was a simple one. The principle of the theorem is "changing the sub-lists of a list and applying the changes to both (both the main list and the sub-list)